# Definite article “the” in “the adult”

Tags: definite-article

“There was a child, and he was fully grown up, and the adult became a cook.”

In this case, is use of “the adult” acceptable?

“A child” and “the adult” mean the same person.

*The: denoting one or more people or things already mentioned*

Comment: Welcome to ELL! It's a good idea to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer. When you accept an answer, it discourages other people from offering answers. Perfect though my answer is , somebody else might have offered an even better explanation if you had waited a little longer. I won't complain if you un-accept it :-)

Comment: Like @JavaLatte said in her answer below, it's acceptable, but for what it's worth, in your example here, someone cannot be a child and be grown up at the same time, as your sentence suggests. "There was a child who grew up, and the adult became a cook" is better.

Comment: @gotube, I would look on that sentence as in a literary style. You could easily imagine something like that in the bible.

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm familiar with the bible, and this still feels wrong. Also, unless a learner of English states they're trying to write in a particular literary style, I assume it's a mistake, accidentally similar to that style, but not on purpose.

Comment: @gotube fair comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable.

The adult is the same person as the child, just grown up. Because it relates to something that has already been mentioned, you can use the definite article.